# Wordpress get custom post type posts by category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

Hi I have some problem with custom post type categories, I try to get all post that have some category but it output all post. Can you help me please.
Thank you.

my code

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => "collection-posts",
    'category'=> 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts($args);
```

but it give all posts. I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments key should be `cat`, not `category`:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => "collection-posts",
    'cat' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: oooo thank you. one day i try to resolve this :D but in wp codex he write category

Comment: @AramMkrtchyan No problem. Really? Where can you see that?

Comment: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) Look :query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use ofpre_get_posts hook, for this purpose. TL;DR don't use query_posts() ever;

Comment: <?php $args = array(
 'posts_per_page'   => 5,
 'offset'           => 0,
 'category'         => '',
 'category_name'    => '',
 'orderby'          => 'date',
 'order'            => 'DESC',
 'include'          => '',
 'exclude'          => '',
 'meta_key'         => '',
 'meta_value'       => '',
 'post_type'        => 'post',
 'post_mime_type'   => '',
 'post_parent'      => '',
 'author'    => '',
 'post_status'      => 'publish',
 'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>

here is the copy of code

Answer (score 0):

I found another solutions. You can also use get `get_posts` method of WordPress and category slug.
For Example : i am assuming your category slug is `collection-posts-category`

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
     'category'  => 'collection-posts-category',
     'post_type' => 'collection-posts',
     'posts_per_page' => 12,
     'paged' => $paged
);
$collection_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Hope this will helpful.